# Как закрыть все поля Toast при закрытии приложения?

Tags: java, android

У меня в приложении при определённых обстоятельствах вылезает поле toast с подсказками. Допустим, поле toast ещё отображается, а приложение закрыли кнопкой "закрыть", которая в приложении, или кнопкой home, а поле Toast продолжит висеть пока не пройдёт его время. Можно ли как-то закрыть toast вместе с приложением?

Comment: Можно - для этого у тоста есть метод [`cancel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#cancel()). Но чтобы его вызвать Вы должны сохранять ссылки на созданные тосты. И закрывать в подходящем методе жизненного цикла. Для примера см. код: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17740590

Comment: Спасибо большое!